# How to retrieve data from excel file using symfony2 excelbundle?

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, phpexcel

For a school project, I have to collect data from an Excel file uploaded by the user. I am using Symfony2 and have installed a bundle I found on knpbundles, named ExcelBundle. I read that to collect data with it from an Excel file, I should use the createWriter method of my phpExcel object. That is what I have done as shown below.

```
public function addContactsFromExcelAction(Request $request) {
    $uploadDir = '/var/www'.$request->getBasePath().'/uploads/';
    //die(var_dump($uploadDir));
    $file = $request->files->get('fichierExcel');
    $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $fileSaved = $file->move($uploadDir,$fileName);
    $phpExcelObject = $this->get('phpexcel')->createPHPExcelObject($uploadDir.$fileName);
    $writer = $this->get('phpexcel')->createWriter($phpExcelObject, 'Excel2007');

}
```

But the thing is that actually, I do not really know how to use the writer to collect data from the cells of my excel datasheets.

Please, could anyone give me the trick to achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can iterate as this Example:

```
public function xlsAction()
{
    $filenames = "your-file-name";
    $phpExcelObject = $this->get('phpexcel')->createPHPExcelObject($filenames);

    foreach ($phpExcelObject ->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
        echo 'Worksheet - ' , $worksheet->getTitle();
        foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
            echo '    Row number - ' , $row->getRowIndex();
            $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
            $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); // Loop all cells, even if it is not set
            foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
                if (!is_null($cell)) {
                    echo '        Cell - ' , $cell->getCoordinate() , ' - ' , $cell->getCalculatedValue();
                }
            }
    }
    }
}
```

More samples [here](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/develop/Examples)